# How to monitor https/ssl traffic in a iOS/Android device

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, ssl

I want to see the page request that sends the content to server in a decrypted form this is for some debugging.

If it requires debugging jail breaking/rooting also ok no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you to use Charles.I have used it myself ocassionaly and I find it easy to use.

You can Install Charles from [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/)

- You have to configure your mobile device(iOS or Android) with Charles
  proxy
- You have to install Charles proxy's SSL Root certificate in your mobile
  device so that SSL traffic can be monitored

Make the following choice to find your Charles IP with Port number with which you have to bind your device and URL of the SSL CA using which you have to install in the device

*Help* -> *SSL Proxying* -> *Install Charless Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser*

[image]

Note down the *IP address with Port number* and note down the *URL* for installing the *CA*

[image]

Binding the HTTP Proxy in iOS Device 
 - Go to Settings -> Wifi -> Connect with wifi hotspot which your system also shares
 - Once connected scroll down to the current wifi and choose *Manual* in *HTTP Proxy*
 - Enter the IP and Port in Server and Port over there

[image]

That's it now you are connect with Charles Proxy and you can monitor all the http traffic

In order to monitor the https traffic.

Enter the noted URL in safari and it will show install prompt give yes and install it.

Now Charles can monitor SSL traffic that originates from the device.But Charles will not show unencrypted SSL traffic for all the sites.You have to add the sites for which you need SSL traffic to be monitored.

Here is how to do it

In Charles Make following selections.

*Proxy* -> *SSL Proxy Settings*

[image]

Click *Add* and enter the *Host* and *Port* of the https site for which you have to monitor the traffic.

[image]

[image]

Voila ! Now you can view the encrypted traffic of https site in Charles.

Visit the site and you should be able to see on the side bar of Charles click that URL and you should be able to see the unencrypted traffic in right side !

### Update

If you are on iOS 10.3 or later, open the Settings.app and navigate to *General > About > Certificate Trust Settings*, and find the Charles Proxy certificate, and *switch it on to enable full trust* for it in order to SSL proxying.

Comment: I have added SSL proxying for all sites and I am unable to access https sites but for http it is working fine

Comment: I have asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48873791/8053184

Comment: Strange ! it should work ! Have you installed the SSL certificate on iOS device ?

Comment: yep I installed by going to the mentioned path "chls.pro/ssl" and it successfully installed

Comment: Can you if the "CHARLES Proxy CA" is trusted ? go to Settings -> General -> Profile then see if its trusted

Comment: I am seeing it is trusted

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a proxy in your Mac/PC. Then use this proxy on your iOS/Android devices. Then you can capture all trafic passed by that proxy. The one I used is WireShark (https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: I don't think with WireShark we can see the traffic in unencrypted form

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Charles. http://www.charlesproxy.com

It is a bit easier to use than Wireshark and has a easy guide for use with iOS devices and simulators.