# Why https request fails on Charles Proxy if SSL proxying is turned on

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I have installed and configured Charles proxy in my mac.

I am able to browse all http sites and see the requests in Charles but I am not able to browse https sites I get unable to connect

> Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure
>   connection.

I have installed the SSL certificate as it is mentioned in Charles but all the https connections are failing

Comment: Do HTTPS request appear on Charles panel? Seems like if your Safari can't reach the proxy port at Charles, could you try it with Chrome (you will probably need to use some proxy extension such as SwitchyOmega) and compare the results to determine if it's Safari's fault or Charles?

Comment: the behaviour is same for both the page is not opening and I can see the requests in Charles panel

Comment: Can you if the "CHARLES Proxy CA" is trusted in device ? go to Settings -> General -> Profile then see if its trusted

Comment: I am seeing its trusted

Comment: Really strange because you are able to see the request that originates from device that means proxy has configured well and https traffic doesn't succeed I thought may be Proxy CA wasn't installed properly.But you have installed it properly and It has been trusted in the device so there should not be any other problem.

Comment: Can you share the version of Charles and iOS that you are using so that we can check if there are any known issues ?

Comment: Charles version : 4.2.1 and iOS version : 11.2.5

Comment: Penny dropped ! Starting from *iOS 10.3* **SSL trust** for the certificate has to be turned on manually so go to **Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings**. Under Enable full trust for root certificates **turn on trust for the certificate**.It should fix the issue I guess.Let me know if it helps

Comment: It started working

Comment: None of these suggestions, or all others Google comes up with, fix it for me. Ever since Catalina I've had a terrible time getting Charles to work with everything - iOS Simulator is that last one I simply can't get to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are on *iOS 10.3 or later*, open the Settings.app and navigate to **General > About > Certificate Trust Settings**, and find the Charles Proxy certificate, and *switch it on to enable full trust for it*

Now you should be able to access SSL websites with Charles using SSL Proxying.

Look into iOS Devices section in the [Charles SSL documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates) for reference

Answer (score 2):

I had to do few extra steps to make Charles work in my ***Mac+iOS*** setup

The device which I was using was the shared between team and had multiple certificate installed for Charles, to solve the issue I tried fresh install of the certificate and it worked

**Step 1** : Remove all exiting certificate

`Settings > General > Profiles`
Check the certificate list for name starting with `Charles Proxy CA`
Click on the Charles certificate and Remove one by one using `Remove profile` option

***Step 2*** : Install new Charles certificate

***2.1*** : Charles (from Mac system) [Documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/#:%7E:text=Launch%20Charles%20and%20go%20to,with%20Charles%20using%20SSL%20Proxying.) -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles root certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote browser

Capture the IP and Port details

***2.2*** : Go to iOS device -> Settings ->Wi-Fi -> Click on the Connected network -> Select Configure Proxy in HTTP Proxy option -> Add IP in Server and Port as 8888 with Authentication off in device

***2.3*** : Open safari and browse chls.pro/ssl
Download the Certificate and install

***2.4*** : trust certificate in Settings > General > Profiles

***2.5*** : Toggle on the General > About > Certificate Trust Settings

Now, restart Charles. You should be able to see the traffic in Charles